# YOLOv3 object detection with camera through RTSP

Tags: python, machine-learning, camera, object-detection, yolo

I'm writing my bachelor's degree work in python and it's about object detection in surveillance systems.
I got a camera, which codec sections are set to DCIF, H264.
As we know OpenCV is capable of capturing video streams through RTSP protocol and so i set it up.

I dunno if the problem is the codecs, but everything seems so (my GPU is not the first-class though as well), because when i used it for the first time using my notebook webcam everything was just fine. I'll put here a part of terminal output, and i gladly ask for some help on how to make it work, because it works for a while (~10secs) and turns out/crashes.
I'm using YOLOv3 convolutional neuronal network model, and as I mentioned it worked pretty fine.

Here's the terminal output:

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x34363258/'X264' is not supported with codec id 27 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x31637661/'avc1'
Could not find encoder for codec id 27: Encoder not found
2020-10-28 18:07:32.655181: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-10-28 18:07:39.985532: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-10-28 18:07:44.088814: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-10-28 18:07:47.001301: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:246] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-10-28 18:07:47.042291: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:246] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.15GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2020-10-28 18:07:47.199933: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:246] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.08GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
[h264 @ 0x560c2b45e4c0] error while decoding MB 11 10, bytestream -6
Detections have been saved successfully.
```

Update: after changing break to continure in try except block i got errors:

```
[h264 @ 0x565266a13880] error while decoding MB 31 18, bytestream -45
[NULL @ 0x565266e16a40] SEI type 40 size 1936 truncated at 736
[NULL @ 0x565266e16a40] missing picture in access unit with size 1136
[h264 @ 0x565266ef4280] no frame!
```

Comment: Similar issue here. I am getting the following                                                         
```myClass: 32% [h264 @ 00000213a99043e0]

FPS:52.8         AVG_FPS:3.4
error while decoding MB 37 19, bytestream -7```